# Meteor + Aldeed Autoform :: How to pass parent data?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

So on my page, there's a list of different books getting rendered from `Books` collection.

For each book, there's a form to add some information about the borrower.

My current template structures are as follows:

```
<template name="bookList">
{{#each book}}
    <div class="book">
    ...
    </div>
    {{> borrowerForm}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="borrowerForm">
    <div class="borrowerForm">
    {{#autoForm schema=borrowerFormSchema id="borrowerForm" type="method" meteormethod="addBorrower" class="hide"}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

I am using `type="method"` for this "borrower" form so that I can modify the `doc` (aka the form input value) with additional object.

Here's how I am doing it currently:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addBorrower: function(doc) {
        if (! Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
        }
        Meteor.users.deny({
            insert: function() {
                return true;
            }
        });
        check(doc, Schemas.borrowerSchema);

        var myData = doc;

        //var bookID = Template.parentData(1)._id;
        //console.log("bookID: " + bookID);

        //myData["bookID"] = bookID;  
        myData["createdBy"] = Meteor.userId();
        myData["createdAt"] = new Date();

        Borrower.insert(myData);
    }
});
```

All seems to work just fine until I need to add one more thing which is the book ID. I'd like to include the book ID that is being borrowed as an additional data alongside `createdBy` and `createdAt`.

The way I grab the book ID is by using `Template.parentData(1)._id` and it does return the correct data (See the commented lines on the above code). However, it's throwing this error below which I don't understand and the form just won't submit at all:

```
M…r.m…e.errorClass {
      error: 500, 
      reason: "Internal server error", 
      details: undefined, 
      message: "Internal server error [500]", 
      errorType: "Meteor.Error"
}
 details: undefined
 error: 500
 errorType: "Meteor.Error"
 message: "Internal server error [500]"
 reason: "Internal server error"stack: (...)
 ▶︎ get stack: () { [native code] }
 ▶︎ set stack: () { [native code] }
 ▶︎ __proto__: Meteor.makeErrorType.errorClass
```

Terminal:

```
  Exception while invoking method 'addBorrower' ReferenceError: Template is not defined
      at [object Object].Meteor.methods.addBorrower (app/common/books.js:42:31)
      at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
      at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
      at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
      at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
      at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
      at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
      at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1
```

Could someone kindly explain what's going on there and how to solve the issue, please? Thanks!

I am a novice in Javascript and Meteor so a simple but clear explanation (with analogies) would be much appreciated too.

Comment: Hey, is your `Meteor.methods` in a file in the server directory or the client directory? There are multiple ways to get the book id.

Comment: I put Meteor.methods inside a folder that is accessible for both client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly move your method into a file in `server/` folder. Also, move your deny rule outside the method.

Now, in your `borrowerForm.onRendered` create a AutoForm hook like:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    borrowerForm: {
        before: {
            method: function( doc ) {
                doc.bookID = Template.parentData(1)._id;
                return doc;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This should work, I haven't tried it though. If it still doesn't, please put your code on MeteorPad and post a link.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work = / Tried MeteorPad but it's buggy on my end. Please have a look at this repo instead: https://bitbucket.org/kyooriouskoala/library/branch/master

Comment: Hey, I've fixed this, please check https://bitbucket.org/keya/library
For some reason, `before` and `method` did not work, so used `formToDoc`.

Comment: Also, please look into using something like https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli to organize your code. Much lesser time spent on figuring out how to organize files and it totally adds to your productivity.

Comment: I'll check out iron-cli! Thanks for your help! I appreciate the solution that you provided and I'm going to use it to continue building the app to learn more about Meteor and JS. Do you happen to have any idea of what went wrong with the way I did it in the first place though?

Comment: The call was being executed in the server side, where the context of Template is unknown. For what I know, the `Template` object is available on the client.
Also, when a you do a method call, you are only passing it the data as parameters, the context of the Template is pretty much unknown, so you will have to fetch it on the client helper and pass it appropriately to the server method. It will all get more obvious as you try more things :)

Comment: Also, the AutoForm hook, `before` -> `method` does not seem to work though, `formToDoc` seems to be the one to use.